# Package org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio does not exist

Tags: java, jar, package, netty, nio

Which JAR contains `org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio`?
I'm **not** using Maven or Ivy, just Ant.

Ant compile gives:

```
-do-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EchoClient/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EchoClient/src/net/bounceme/dur/netty/client/ObjectEchoClient.java:3: error: package org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio does not exist
    [javac] import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory;
```

In the classpath is:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EchoClient/nbproject$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EchoClient/nbproject$ head -n 58 project.properties | tail -n 29
endorsed.classpath=
excludes=
file.reference.netty-all-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/all-in-one/netty-all-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-all-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/all-in-one/netty-all-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-buffer-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-buffer-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-buffer-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-buffer-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-http-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-http-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-http-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-http-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-socks-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-socks-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-codec-socks-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-codec-socks-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-common-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-common-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-common-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-common-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-example-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-example-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-example-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-example-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-handler-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-handler-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-handler-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-handler-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-tcnative-1.1.30.Fork2-linux-x86_64.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-tcnative-1.1.30.Fork2-linux-x86_64.jar
file.reference.netty-tcnative-1.1.30.Fork2-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-tcnative-1.1.30.Fork2-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-sctp-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-sctp-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-sctp-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-sctp-4.0.21.Final.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-udt-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-udt-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar
file.reference.netty-transport-udt-4.0.21.Final.jar=/home/thufir/jars/netty-4.0.21.Final/jar/netty-transport-udt-4.0.21.Final.jar
includes=**
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EchoClient/nbproject$
```

The library is `netty-4.0.21.Final.tar.bz2`, which was downloaded from the official Netty [website](https://netty.io/downloads.html).

I added each JAR from that download to the project. Yes, I realize it's not using the CLI `javac` classpath, but the JAR's are visible in the project, as well as in the output above.

I looked through some of the JAR's and was unable to find this specific class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to build an application developed against Netty 3.x using **Netty 4.0**.

There have been [API changes](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html), including channel creation and bootstrap. Also, the package prefix changed from `org.jboss.netty` to `io.netty` reflecting the project status change.

Use the [API documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html) (which no longer documents `NioClientSocketChannelFactory`) corresponding to the release you're using and checkout the provided examples (*netty-example-4.0.21.Final-sources.jar*) to help port any code you have that's built against Netty 3.x.

Comment: mystery solved!  The sample code was from the github repository for netty.  I'll take a closer look at this tomorrow before I accept answer, to be sure that I understand what's going on.